# When can insulation against external walls be done for new construction?

Tags: insulation

Picture a new construction house where wood framing is complete and a roof has been added. How soon can insulation against external walls be added? Are there other steps that must be completed prior to insulating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pulled a permit for this work, you should not proceed until you have your framing, rough electrical, and rough plumbing inspections signed off. Depending on the work, there may be more inspections you should wait for (i.e. rafter tie-down straps, rough mechanical...) your building permit likely has these listed in order on the signoff card, or just call and ask the building official.

If you did not pull a permit, I'm sure you would prefer to get it in ASAP before the temps drop.

Comment: Does it matter if there isn’t yet any paper or covering on the wood on the outside of the house? Or if the wood got a little wet from angled rain, perhaps, it wouldn’t matter to the insulation?